# How host my own disposable email?

Tags: open-source, email, self-hosted, privacy, smtp

I am looking for a solution to host my own disposable email server.

Like yopmail, or temp-mail.

Does someone know of an open source solution?

I saw:

https://github.com/o4oren/Ad-Hoc-Email-Server

But its seem very big for me. I prefer a simple solution.

Maybe a library for Python?

Thanks

Comment: The answer possible :
Make a catch-all and use hmailserver

Answer (score 1):

GuerrillaMail.com is very similar to the sites you mention, and the core of it appears to be this open source project:

https://github.com/flashmob/go-guerrilla

It's not a turnkey solution, but it could be a good start toward building your own version.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for disposable inboxes, try https://inboxen.org/

If you are looking for disposable addresses, try https://simplelogin.io/

Both are open source and can be self-hosted.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your requirements to *disposable* are, but you could have a look at the [dockerized version](https://github.com/mailcow/mailcow-dockerized) of [mailcow](https://mailcow.email/). It contains everything you need for a mailsetup.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking for it to have a domain name (`@example.com`) you control receive email, no matter what username is (`random@example.com`, `booboo@example.com', etc...) but be able to access its content.

If it's not as important a requirement that you host your own server, sounds that what you need is an easy to manage DNS/mail routing system.

I use the [ZoneEdit.com](https://zoneedit.com) DNS service, it's free tier, which has `mailmaps`.
It allows me to setup subdomains as well as wildcard matching, so I have disposable addresses for all of my house hold:

> ```
> - *@junk.example.com
> - *@junk.wife.example.com
> - *@junk.son.example.com
> etc...
> ```

This way I also have multiple domains, and they are router accordingly to the end mailbox without polluting my identity online.

Of course you can tie this with any mail-server of your choice, self-hosted or otherwise.